# Convert existing asp.net web application to MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an existing asp.net web application which I need to convert to mvc3.

As soon as I add the below my project's web.config, the project stops working I am using IIS 5. I guess I have missed something in IIS, please advise

```
 <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Comment: Stops working?!? An error message perhaps?

Comment: Got the answer from this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727309/webforms-and-asp-net-mvc-co-existence

Answer (score 0):

First confirm if any MVC3 project works with IIS5 the way you have it configured, you may need to setup the wildcard rule and uncheck verify if file exsists. Once you have done this what I do is just create a new MVC3 project that is empty and move over my stuff from the old project to the new project. That is the least hassel free way of doing it. Keep the namespace of the solution the same so you don't have to deal with namespace mismatch issues.